# How to convert substring to datetime

Tags: asp.net

I have a date time value extracted from textbox (datepicker) which is a range of time however i use sub string to further divide the time range to admissionDT and dischargeDT.However i cannot convert the substring into DateTime as i wanted to insert them into the database.The error displayed was  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
string admissionDischargeDT = adDT.Text;
string admissionDT = admissionDischargeDT.Substring(0,17);
string dischargeDT = admissionDischargeDT.Substring(18,17);

DateTime admissionDTinput = DateTime.ParseExact(admissionDT,"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dischargeDTinput = Convert.ToDateTime(dischargeDT);
```

Below are the codes for the datepicker found in the aspx.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2">Admission Date & Time</label>

            <div class =" col-lg-10">
            <div class="input-group">

        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar22"></i></span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="adDT" type="text" runat="server" class="form-control daterange-time" value=""></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: What's the value of the string you're trying to parse?  The error would suggest that it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: The value is 12/28/2016 12:00 am - 12/28/2016 11:59 pm . I'm trying to extract this value from the datepicker which is a textbox.

Comment: `"12/28/2016 12:00 am"` doesn't match the format string `"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm tt"`.  "ParseExact" really does mean *exact*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you say:

> The value is 12/28/2016 12:00 am

But your format string is:

```
"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm tt"
```

That doesn't match the input.  It sounds like the format you want is:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"
```

- You were using `-` instead of `/`
- You were using minutes instead of months
- Your day/month values were transposed (there is no 28th month)